# SharePoint 2013 and ISA 2006

Tags: extranet

I am pretty sure I am stretching, but I have a client that is on SharePoint 2013. They want to expose externally and wish to use ISA 2006 (long story on why). My core question is whether it will work. I have seen that it is not truly supported, but will it work.

In theory I would suspect it should work since it is really just HTTP\HTTPS traffic forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I was to get it to work just fine. The person that configured it originally had set the rule to basic authentication. Of course SharePoint requires NTLM Authentication.

I just followed the standard SharePoint 2010 configuration.